# jqGrid 4.5.2 - jQuery Grid: giving rendering issues during jquery upgrade to 3.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, rendering, free-jqgrid

Im upgrading jquery version to 3.6.1 and for that im also taking the help of jquery migrate plugin. My applcation is also using jquery jqgrid-4.5.2(very old one) by Tony Tomov, to  display data in tabular form.

Now by seeing the logs in my console thrown by jquery migrate plugin, i think that jquery jqgrid is not compatible with jquery 3.6.1 and because im also getting rendering issues during the page load.

When i checked in internet i found that latest version jqgrid is paid ,so i looked for a free fork and found one that is free jqgrid(4.15.5). But with that also im facing the same problem .
Im very new to these softwares. Can anyone please suggest me a solution here?
Am i using the wrong version of free jqgrid and if yes then please suggest me a version which is compatible with jquery 3.6.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery 3.6.1 was released August 2022 and has significant changes. Both jqGrid 4.5.x and free-jqGrid does not support this version of jQuery.

The jQuery Migrate plugin maybe will not help. The jQuery team spoke that in most cases the Migrate plugin:

> will help you to identify compatibility issues in your code

but does not solve the problem.

I recommend you to contact the Guriddo team , which support and develop the current jqGrid - in all cases you will find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering and clearing my doubts